# Assign concrete class to variable

Tags: python, abstract-class, mypy, type-hinting

I have a situation where I want to choose which implementation of an ABC I want to use based on some condition:

```py
class Base(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def func(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Foo(Base):
    def func(self) -> str:
        return 'foo'

class Bar(Base):
    def func(self) -> str:
        return 'bar'

def call_func(use_foo: bool) -> str:
    cls: type[Base] = Foo if use_foo else Bar
    return cls().func()
```

This runs just fine but mypy 1.9.0 complains

> Can only assign concrete classes to a variable of type "type[Base]"

Comment: Do other type checkers complain? This may be a mypy bug or limitation.

Comment: Do you get a similar complaint if you use an `if` statement instead of conditional expression?

Comment: The error emitted is because mypy sees the equivalent of `cls: type[Base] = Base`, which errors because `Base` still has an abstract method (so it is illegal to do `Base()` at runtime). I suspect the underlying issue is because mypy uses join operations instead of union operations (see https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12056).

Comment: @Barmar, switching to an `if` statement fixes the issue.

Comment: @Barmar, neither `pytype` nor `pyright` detect any errors.

Comment: The *assignment* should be fine, type-wise. It's the call to `cls()` that should raise an error, because no matter what the *dynamic* type of `cls` is, the static type cannot guaranteed that `cls` is a concrete class.

Comment: @chepner you're right in theory, but (unfortunately?), mypy models an arbitrary class `A` as `Callable[<constructor parameters>, A]` (you can confirm this with `reveal_type(Base)`).

Comment: I'm not sure that's relevant. `cls: type[Base] = Foo` is fine; it's the conditional expression that causes the problem, which suggests that `mypy` is doing some sort of overly conservative guess at whether a class is abstract or concrete, so that `cls()` can always be considered safe.

Comment: (I.e., if the source is a single name like `Foo`, it will look to the definition, but it doesn't look closer at anything more syntactically complex like `Foo if use_foo else Bar`.)

Comment: No, the `Callable[..., Base]` modelling as a result of the join operation is almost certainly what's causing the issue - `reveal_type(Foo if use_foo else Bar)` brings up `def () -> Base` in mypy.

Comment: +1 to @dROOOze, it's almost definitely a join-vs-meet issue. [`basedmypy`](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) fork reverts that decision (uses union for ternary) and does not report the error mentioned in post.